# Mount qcow2 image using qemu-nbd within a container

Tags: virtualization, lxc, qemu

I'm trying to get an OpenStack Nova compute node running within a container to boot a server in a nested container.

Everything works fine until I ask Nova in the controller to boot the server. During the server boot process in the compute container, libvirt uses qemu-nbd to export the qcow2 disk image downloaded from OpenStack Glance as a previous step to launching the nested container. With the default lxc configuration qemu-nbd fails.

I've worked out the lxc.conf file to allow using qemu-nbd from within the container, but I must be missing something because even if the container activates the node /dev/nbd0 I can't see the /dev/nbd0p1 entry corresponding to the partition in the qcow2 disk image.

Here's the lxc.conf file for my Nova container:

```
# Template used to create this container: /usr/share/lxc/templates/lxc-download
# Parameters passed to the template: -d ubuntu -r trusty -a i386
# For additional config options, please look at lxc.container.conf(5)

# Distribution configuration
lxc.include = /usr/share/lxc/config/ubuntu.common.conf
lxc.arch = x86

# Container specific configuration
lxc.rootfs = /var/lib/lxc/compute/rootfs
lxc.utsname = compute

# Network configuration
lxc.network.type = veth
lxc.network.flags = up
lxc.network.link = lxcbr0
lxc.network.hwaddr = 00:16:3e:90:16:e0

lxc.network.type = veth
lxc.network.flags = up
lxc.network.link = br0.1000
lxc.network.hwaddr = 00:16:3e:90:16:e1

# This is the public interface
lxc.network.type = veth
lxc.network.flags = up
lxc.network.link = br0.2000
lxc.network.hwaddr = 00:16:3e:90:16:e2

# Added so certain functions (iptables, nova-compute, ...) work
lxc.mount.entry = /lib/modules/3.13.0-43-generic     /var/lib/lxc/compute/rootfs/lib/modules/3.13.0-43-generic none ro,bind 0 0

# Added so the compute node can run LXC VMs
lxc.mount.auto = cgroup
lxc.aa_profile = lxc-container-default-with-nesting

# Allow the container to mknod (needed by qemu-nbd...)
lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c *:* m
lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = b *:* m

# Allow the container to use the host's nbd devices
lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = b 43:* rwm # Every nbd device in the host
```

It can be verified easily on the command line. Assuming we have the qcow disk image in `/root/cirros-0.3.3-i386-disk.img`:

```
root@compute:~# qemu-nbd -c /dev/nbd0 cirros-0.3.3-i386-disk.img -f qcow2
root@compute:~# ls -d /sys/class/block/nbd0p1
/sys/class/block/nbd0  /sys/class/block/ndb0p1
root@compute:~# ls /dev/nbd0*
/dev/nbd0
```

It seems the block device exists in the kernel, but the /dev/nbd0p1 device node has not been created. Anyone knows what am I missing in my container configuration?

P.S. I know OpenStack Nova by default doesn't work with container VMs, there are some changes I need to do in Nova code; but I need to overcome this hurdle first

Comment: Is udev running inside your container? I'm running a whole OpenStack cloud inside libvirt-lxc containers without problems, but I use libvirt-lxc to create the containers.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work for me (booting LXC instance using cirros qcow2 image inside LXC host inside KVM guest on top of KVM host; Icehouse release).

Did have to manually create a few nbd nodes:

```
stack@ctl-template:~/devstack$ ls -l /dev/nbd*
brw-r--r-- 1 root root 43,  0 Apr 13 14:31 /dev/nbd0
brw-r--r-- 1 root root 43, 16 Apr 13 14:33 /dev/nbd1
brw-r--r-- 1 root root 43, 32 Apr 13 14:33 /dev/nbd2
brw-r--r-- 1 root root 43, 48 Apr 13 14:33 /dev/nbd3
brw-r--r-- 1 root root 43, 64 Apr 13 14:34 /dev/nbd4
```

nbd1 is being used by the instance:

```
stack@ctl-template:~/devstack$ dmesg | tail | grep nbd
[94516.110986] EXT4-fs (nbd1): mounting ext3 file system using the ext4 subsystem
[94516.205551] EXT4-fs (nbd1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts:
```

no additional devices created for partition(s) inside the image:

```
stack@ctl-template:~/devstack$ ls /sys/class/block/
loop0  loop4  nbd0   nbd12  nbd2  nbd6  ram0   ram12  ram2  ram6  sr0   vda5
loop1  loop5  nbd1   nbd13  nbd3  nbd7  ram1   ram13  ram3  ram7  vda
loop2  loop6  nbd10  nbd14  nbd4  nbd8  ram10  ram14  ram4  ram8  vda1
loop3  loop7  nbd11  nbd15  nbd5  nbd9  ram11  ram15  ram5  ram9  vda2
```